# How to convert table into Columns using VB

Tags: excel, vba

I got indulge in preparing one VB macro.

I am preparing one Excel macro using VB to convert a table data into two columns.

I need to concatenate the stations and departments into one column and respective value into adjacent column.

I have table as below:

[image]

and I need the data into 2 columns as below:

[image]

Comment: What code have you tried? What logic were you considering? And what problem did you run into in constructing the logic or the implementation?

Comment: please use the correct tags

Answer (score 1):

This assumes the table is in **A1** thru **I6** and the output goes in columns **J** and **K**

```
Sub MakeColumns()
    Dim I As Long, J As Long, K As Long
    K = 1
    For I = 2 To 6
        For J = 2 To 9
            Cells(K, 11).Value = Cells(I, J).Value
            Cells(K, 10).Value = Cells(I, 1).Value & " " & Cells(1, J).Value
            K = K + 1
        Next J
    Next I
End Sub
```

Comment: Thats a slick solution

Comment: @mrbungle Thanks!  it is also quite easy to modify for an size table.

Comment: @garysstudent no doubt that this was copied over to my evernote workbook with the vba tag for future reference